# Dart lang: How do you browser feature test for file uploading & file reading APIs?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

How do you feature test for browser support using Dart? Things that are common to test for in Javascript. It is unfortunately still a necessary evil.

For instance, how do you write a test if the browser supports 'XMLHttpRequestUpload' so that you can fallback to supported features?

Also, how do you test for 'FileReader', 'Worker', 'ArrayBuffer', 'DataView', 'Uint8Array', 'Float32Array', ... ?

In Javascript, you can test if the objects are available in the global namespace (Window, etc).

Answer (score 1):

To check if you can access the file system use the [FileSystem.supported](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/FileSystem.html#supported) field. Similarly for workers see [Worker.supported](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Worker.html#supported).

Since Dart targets IE9+, I think the other API's you've listed are already supported cross browser.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. That's elegant. Is there anyway to test for things that don't have that "supported" value? I'm trying to evaluate if I can use Dart to build web apps that work on browser that aren't the in Dart's target browsers.

Comment: You can use js interop. http://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/ Assuming that it is IE8 that you're targeting, getting Dart code to work in IE8 is likely to be a painful experience. Also worth noting that XP officially turns into a pumpkin sometime this year. Which means apart from China, there's likely to be a large sudden reduction in IE8 users.

Comment: Appreciated. I've been using Google Closure Library / Compiler. Lots of painful experiences doing things for compatibility. Albeit, even Firefox didn't support 'DataView' until August last year. It appears Dart is now mature enough to consider it for production. Evaluating what I lose and gain switching from Closure.